# Viewing picture based on EXIF data from url in android

Tags: android, url, exif

I am trying to view image from url in android application by following code:

```
img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);

new LoadImage().execute("http://localhost" + file_name);
```

It works pretty well, but it ignores EXIF data of an image, so my image is rotated. How to view images depending on their EXIF data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call fixOrientation to fix your image orientation

```
public static int getExifRotation(String imgPath) {
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imgPath);
        String rotationAmount = exif
                .getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(rotationAmount)) {
            int rotationParam = Integer.parseInt(rotationAmount);
            switch (rotationParam) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    return 0;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    return 90;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    return 180;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    return 270;
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return 0;
    }
}

public static Bitmap fixOrientation(String filePath, Bitmap bm) {
    int orientation = getExifRotation(filePath);
    if (orientation == 0 || orientation % 360 == 0) {
        //it is already right orientation, no need to rotate
        return bm;
    }
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(orientation);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);
}
```

I suggest you use modern image loader like Glide or Fresco instead of handling the image directly with AsyncTask.

Comment: I used Glide. Thank you.

Comment: It returns FileNotFoundException on the url of the image

Comment: Are you sure that your image url is right? You can test it in your browser. Show your url here, so we can solve it together

Comment: yep, it works in my browser and it's oriented right.